# Does $x^T(M+M^T)x \geq 0 \implies x^TMx \geq 0$ hold in only one direction?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know this is true for the "if" part, but what about the "only if"?

Can you give me one example when the "only if" part does not hold? I am not quite sure about this.

I forgot to tell you that $M$ is real and $x$ arbitrary.

Comment: Here $x$ is fixed or arbitrary?

Comment: x is arbitrary and $M$ is real. I guess this is true in both directions, but I recall to see that this only works in one direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$M=\frac{M+M^T}2+\frac{M-M^T}2$ and $x^T\left(\frac{M-M^T}2\right)x=0$ for *every* real vector $x$ (because $x^TMx=(x^TMx)^T=x^TM^Tx$). Therefore $x^TMx\ge0$ if and only if $x^T\left(\frac{M+M^T}2\right)x\ge0$.

Answer (score 2):

Well

$x^{T}Mx \geq 0 \implies x^{T}M^{T}x \geq 0$ (by taking transpose)

Hence, $x^{T}(M^{T} + M)x \geq 0$.

So, this gives you the one side. However, you wrote the converse in your title.